# Loopback 3 / Where Filter / LIKE / MSSQL Connector Error

Tags: node.js, rest, api, loopback

I'm using the mssql connector and can't get any hits using the LIKE operator. I've tried all sorts of combinations. I understand it depends on the connector so it should be % but it fails.

**http://.....?filter={"where":{"businessName":{"like":"%National%"}}}**

( Returns 400 Cannot Parse JSON-encoded object value. )

**http://.....?filter={"where":{"businessName":{"like":"National"}}}**

(Returns 0 Results)

**http://.....?filter={"where":{"businessName":{"like":"*.National.*"}}}**

(Returns 0 Results)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs to know, just encode with %25 ..

http://.....?filter={"where":{"businessName":{"like":"%25National%25"}}}